# Как работать с подобными сайтами как инстаграм?

Tags: java, парсер, бот, htmlunit

я пытаюсь написать бота, который авторизируется в инсте, но как-то не работает. Может есть какие-нибудь специальные библиотеки, чтобы можно было заполнять поля, нажимать кнопки и тп(по принципу работы селениума). Я работаю с htmlunit

Comment: `по принципу работы селениума` - чем селениум не нравится? Ну и сначала всегда проверяйте, есть ли у сайта API, если есть, то лучше его использовать.

Comment: Мне нужно использование без api инсты, а селениум с головой, тем самым медленный, мне нужно что-то быстрое, работающее без головы(через консоль крч)

Comment: ну то есть вам надо забить в гугл `headless browser`

Comment: так я забивал, выдало htmlunit, а он не делает походу то что мне надо

Comment: а мне выдало [википедию](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser), там есть какой то список браузеров.

Comment: [Running Selenium with Headless Chrome Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53657215/312041)

Comment: Селениум медленный даже без головы